# R/zoo: duplicate index entries in ‘order.by’ are not unique

Tags: r, xts, zoo

I have an excel file containing 3 columns of data against a column of time at one hour interval. I tried to convert the data into a zoo object. But everytime i tried to that there is an error that says "In zoo(y, order.by = index(x), ...) : some methods for “zoo” objects do not work if the index entries in ‘order.by’ are not unique".

```
> datos_meterologicos <- read_excel(datos, sheet = "Precip")
> idx <- as.Date(datos_meterologicos$Fecha)
> date.matrix <- as.data.frame(datos_meterologicos[,-1])
> date.xts <- as.xts(date.matrix,order.by=idx)
> date.zoo <- as.zoo(date.xts)
Warning message:
In zoo(y, order.by = index(x), ...) :
  some methods for “zoo” objects do not work if the index entries in ‘order.by’ are not unique
```

I looked up some of the solutions from other case with the same conflict that I Have, so I tried the next code
`datos_meterologicos$Fecha <- read.zoo(datos_meterologicos, FUN=as.POSIXct, format = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M", tz="UTC"). But I get the same error.`
The data is right here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oV2uk5LIL9aFy3Eepw0WkIWucI3_GgkV/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=115562552506837112131&rtpof=true&sd=true

Answer (score 2):

You are transforming the your datetime values into a date with `as.Date`. You need to add the time as well otherwise you have 24 values of 1 day instead of the day and the hours. Using `as.POSIXct` will preserve your times.

```
idx <- as.POSIXct(datos_meterologicos$Fecha)
# rest of your code...
```

Comment: Thank you, It worked. I aprecciate the help.